# if $\frac{o(x)}{x} \rightarrow 0$, then $o(x) \rightarrow 0$? Peano rest

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion

I have an question about peano rest in taylor series. Let consider that in use of example: 
$$ f(x) = \cos(x) $$

Let consider $f$ as series in use of taylor with peano rest (for example to $x^4$)
$$ f(x) = \cos(x) = 1 - \frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}+o(x^4)$$
where $o(x^4)$ is "small o notation"

### What I know

From theorem I know that 
$$\frac{o(x^4)}{x^4} \rightarrow 0 \text{ when } x\rightarrow 0$$

### My doubts

Does it mean that 
$$o(x^4) \rightarrow 0 \text{ when } x\rightarrow 0 \text{?}$$
I think yes because $x$ is getting smaller and smaller and we divide by them but it is only idea, not formal substantiation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're correct. For, suppose $f(x)=o(x^4)$ as $x \to 0$. Then,
$$\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) =  \lim_{x \to 0}\left( x^4 \cdot \frac{f(x)}{x^4}\right) = 0.$$

Comment: Ahh, thanks a lot! Now I fully understand that

Comment: It's my pleasure. I appreciate the opportunity to talk math with people.